# Material-UI Table Collapsible Rows in-line with regular rows

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v4 and I'm trying to get my collapsible row columns to be in-line with my regular columns.
I posted a photo below along with the code. You can see that when I expand the Frozen Yogurt row, the columns aren't inline with the headings (dessert, calories, fat, carbs, protein). Is it possible to get the columns in the collapsible row to line up with the table headings? I also want them to stay in-line when the screen is re-sized.

[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIbwv.png)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown";
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp";

const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      borderBottom: "unset"
    }
  }
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
  return {
    name,
    calories,
    fat,
    carbs,
    protein,
    price,
    history: [
      { date: "2020-01-05", customerId: "11091700", amount: 3 },
      { date: "2020-01-02", customerId: "Anonymous", amount: 1 }
    ]
  };
}

function Row(props) {
  const { row } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useRowStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableRow className={classes.root}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box margin={1}>
              <Table aria-label="purchases">
                <TableBody>
                  {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                    <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <IconButton
                          aria-label="expand row"
                          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                        >
                          {open ? (
                            <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
                          ) : (
                            <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
                          )}
                        </IconButton>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        Inline with dessert column
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align = 'right'>Inline with calories</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Inline with fat</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Inline with carbs</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Inline with protein</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: PropTypes.string.isRequired
      })
    ).isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5)
];

export default function CollapsibleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify negative margin as I think that should solve your issue. I have added it as inline style, but you can use it by adding an object inside `makeStyles`

```js
<IconButton
  style={{ marginLeft: "-24px" }}
  aria-label="expand row"
  onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
  {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
</IconButton>;
```